# Laplacian raised to positive integer

Tags: pseudo-differential-operators

In books about Pseudo-differential operators, they use many times

$\triangle^k u$

but i have a question, what means this really

option A

$\displaystyle{\sum_{|\alpha|=k}}{\, \frac{k!}{\alpha!} \left({\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_{1}^2}}\right)^{\alpha_{1}} \! \! \! \! ...\left({\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_{n}^2}}\right)^{\alpha_{n}} \! \! \! u(x)} $

option B

$\displaystyle{\sum_{|\alpha|=k}}{\, \frac{k!}{\alpha!} \left({\frac{\partial^{2\alpha_{1}} }{\partial x_{1}^{2\alpha_{1}}}}\right)...\left({\frac{\partial^{2\alpha_{n}} }{\partial x_{n}^{2\alpha_{n}}}}\right)  u(x)} $

Option A means: for each $i$, take $\left({\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_{i}^2}}\right)$ and make $\left({\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_{i}^2}}\right)...\left({\dfrac{\partial^2 }{\partial x_{i}^2}}\right)$, $\alpha_{i}$ times, (just multiply)

Option B means: for each $x_{i}$ take derivate $2\alpha_{i}$-th

thanks so much

Comment: Options A and B are the same, are they not?  Taking $2$ derivatives $n$ times is the same as taking $2n$ derivatives.

Comment: yeah i now see this. thanks